# Does a "tip" that goes 100% to a user for a subscription need to use IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I noticed Clubhouse added tipping which reportedly isn't counted as IAP by Apple. In an app I'd like to allow users to subscribe to another users content and take none of the money. This seems like the tipping use case and wouldn't require the use of IAP.

Is that correct?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you wouldn't need to use in-app purchases for this. Apple calls them "Person-to-Person Services." From the [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#person-to-person-services):

> 3.1.3(d) Person-to-Person Services: If your app enables the purchase of realtime person-to-person services **between two individuals** (for example tutoring students, medical consultations, real estate tours, or fitness training), you may **use purchase methods other than in-app purchase** to collect those payments. One-to-few and one-to-many realtime services must use in-app purchase.